# Addational rendering in react useEffect

Tags: reactjs

here is a cover upload scenarion in my MERN project. When cover changes and user data updates, I also send dependency for run useEffect and getting updated data. But.. one rerender not enough and need more rerender for deploy updates. How can I do this?

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function GetUser(userId) {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users?authenticationId=${userId}`
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setTargetUser(data.data.us[0]);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error fetching data:', error);
        });
    }
    GetUser(Id);
  }, [Id, rerenderCurrentUser]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by one render is not enough? Please add more context to the problem

Comment: if I want to see updated cover in user profile page, it need one more render component. I have fix this issue already by adding one more render in setTimeout. So 1: when changed cover Image + setRerenderCurrentUser(true) and in useEffect code added bellow setTargetUser one more setRerenderCurrentUser(false) in setTimeout(() => {}, 100) and it works. If i try set timeout for example 10, not works. Earlaer i had same problem and fixed it with same way, but I think shoulde be better solution and wanted found any.

Comment: You shoud use `useState` and `useEffect` hooks together to achieve what you asking .if you can setup a `codesandbox ` I could help you with this without knowing the logic I can't do anything please post the code .